# Oracle Sql to "create" records based on fields

Tags: oracle

In Oracle I have a table with 5 fields:

ID

PublishDate

StartDate

EndDate

Value

The idea here is that I want to 'generate' records that are between StartDate and EndDate with the same values as the ID, PublishDate, & Value of those records.

ie this

```
10, 11/20/2014, 1/1/2016, 3/1/2016, 10
```

turns into

```
10, 11/20/2014, 1/1/2016, 10
10, 11/20/2014, 2/1/2016, 10
10, 11/20/2014, 3/1/2016, 10
```

So I've done this in a proc where I'm looping over each record and generating records, but I'm wondering if there is a SQL way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CONNECT BY clause for hierarchical queries:

```
select * from (select 10 id, '11/20/2014' PublishDate, '1/1/2016' StartDate, '3/1/2016' EndDate, 10 value 
               from dual connect by level <= 10);
```

`CONNECT BY level <= N` will produce N copies of each row of the table

For your case:

```
SELECT ID, PublishDate, StartDate + lvl, VALUE
FROM your_tab
     JOIN (SELECT LEVEL - 1 lvl FROM dual
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT round(MAX(trunc(EndDate) - trunc(StartDate))) FROM your_tab)
          )
    ON trunc(EndDate) - trunc(StartDate) >= lvl
```

Comment: Sorry this is a generic example looking for a generic solution. Can't assume any of the field values. Sorry that was my fault to not show that. This also doesn't seem to fill in the days.

Comment: @user441521 Sorry, I didn't look at the output carefully. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Do you know if this is a very slow process? The query hasn't come back yet for me in my situation when I adopt your second example for my specific table. No error, just never finishes.

Comment: @user441521 Which Oracle version are you using?